# Nmap ssl-enum-ciphers not showing ciphers with specific certificate running MS SQL 2019

Tags: nmap

I have a server running MS Sql 2019 Std.I have configured MS SQL to use SSL. I have a cert from entrust that when I scan with Nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers fqdn does not show the TLS version for port 1433. If I switch the cert for MS SQL to one that was issued by our internal CA to use for RDP the scan shows the TLS versions for port 1433.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be the Entrust issued certificate is not working/not trusted.

Comment: I can enumerate the certificate suing this python command: python3 get_tds_cert.py  fqdn 1433.

Comment: I have installed IIS and created a binding with the cert and it will show the TLS version using Nmap on port 443. Very strange issue.